# How to add circular padding to a cardview?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to add circular padding to my cardview but cant find a way to do it.
here's my code for tht cardview and I want add circular padding to cardViewOuter.

```
public void CreateCardViewWithImageView(Uri uri) {

    //CardView
    final CardView cardviewOuter;
    cardviewOuter = new CardView(context);

    cardviewOuter.setId(++pos);
    cardviewOuter.setLayoutParams((new CardView.LayoutParams(800, 800)));
    cardviewOuter.setContentPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
    cardviewOuter.setRadius(height/2);
    cardviewOuter.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    //Imageiew
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setId(pos);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new ImageMatrixTouchHandler(context));
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).resize(screenWidth,screenHeight).into(imageView);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    cardviewOuter.addView(imageView);
    frameLayout.addView(cardviewOuter);

}
```

Comment: Try adding this line: `cardViewOuter.setPreventCornerOverlap(false)`. Or try adding margin to your ImageView.

Comment: both methods didnt worked. btw I'm using an ImageView inside that card which can be zoomed in or out and also I have onTouchListener for cardviewOuter. is that causing a problem?  @Bob